# How can i list all files in the perforce depot with their last modified time

Tags: perforce

I'd like to list all of the files in the perforce depot with the date they were last modified. P4 files shows latest changelist, but not date, and I don't want to have to issue something like fstat for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of files + many fstats you could use fstat directly, fstat can also return results for many files for example for all files under //depot/mydir1/mydir2/...

You can use the -T parameter to filter fields. Check out the docs for fstat: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/fstat.html

Comment: The command I ended up using is:  p4 fstat -Sd -T 'depotFile, headTime' ${your path} | tee fileage